# Copying value in assembly language

Tags: assembly

Consider

```
mov reg, 5
```

where `reg` is considered to be some register. This statement copies the value `5` to a register.

**My Question is:**
If the mentioned register is divided into two parts, higher and lower, which part of the register will store the value and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registers in CPU are usually implemented with "bits", each "bit" holds from logical point of view value 0 or 1 (unless you want to talk about quantum computers, I will assume you mean common CPUs like x86, ARM, Z80, ...).

Integer values in assembler source, like `mov reg,5` are then during assembly process converted into binary encoding: `5 = 0b101`. If target `reg` is 16 bit register, after executing the instruction it will hold binary value 0000_0000_0000_0101 (which when interpreted as decimal integer is "5"). Now if you split that 16 bit register into high and low 8 bit values, those will be 0000_0000 (high 8 bits), 0000_0101 (low 8 bits).

In math terms the **16** bit register can hold values (when the bits are interpreted as unsigned integer values) from range 0..65535 (65535 = 2<sup>**16**</sup>-1). If it contains some value *V*, then the top **8** bits contain value *V_high = V div 256* (256 = 2<sup>**8**</sup>, and "div" means integer division with truncating result), and lower **8** bits contain value *V_low = V mod 256*.

To compose the two values back into original 16 bit value: *V = V_high * 256 + V_low*.

Or from point of view of "bit manipulation" functions: *V = (V_high<<8) | V_low*. (ORing the two values after shifting the V_high to it's proper position 8 bits "left/up"). And *V_high = `shr V,8`* (doing "div 256" by right shift), *V_low = `and V,0xFF`* (doing "mod 256" by using `and` to clear upper bits and keep only 8 lower ones).

In hexadecimal formatting each digit is exactly 4 bits "wide", so by using hexadecimal formatting you can easily "see" single bits set, like 0xA521 = 0b1010_0101_0010_0001, and after splitting that value into two 8 bit parts you will get 0xA5 from high 8 bits, and 0x21 from low 8 bits. (0xA521 = 42273 = 165*256 + 33, 165 is 0xA5, 33 is 0x21).

In answer to your question, both registers will PARTIALLY store the value 5, one storing its high bits (all zeroes), the other storing its low bits (still value 5 (bits 1_0_1) as long as we are talking about "part" of at least 3 bits size).

Also notice how the register always contains only the bit values, nothing else. How you interpret those (signed/unsigned integer, IEEE-754 floating point number, 16 0/1 true/false boolean array, or some completely custom interpretation) is up to the code, which does use the register value.

For example 32 bit value 1095069860 = 0x414570a4 = 0b01000001010001010111000010100100 is about 1 billion when interpreted as 32 bit integer (both signed and unsigned), but when you interpret those bits as 32 bit IEEE 754 "float", it means value `12.340000152587890625` (closest possible value to the "12.34" I did enter into asm source). The register itself is not aware, what the bits are supposed to mean, the meaning is given by the following code using the bit values.

Answer (score 1):

In x86, mov always loads a whole register. It loads the register named in the instruction. But the named register might be part of another register. For example, cx is the low 16 bits of ecx.

Other processor architectures have other ways to load partial registers. For example, MIPS has lui to load the upper half of a register.